# Conditional Nested Navigator gives error "A navigator can only contain a 'Screen', 'Group' or 'React.Fragment' as its direct children (found '')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I have a 'shows' screen which has a list of shows, clicking goes to a show detail page. On the detail page, it has 3 tabs, but one is hidden if feedurl is blank. This throws an error when navigating to various shows that have feedurl's and then don't have feedsurls:

```
Error: A navigator can only contain 'Screen', 'Group' or 'React.Fragment' as its direct children (found ''). To render this component in the navigator, pass it in the 'component' prop to 'Screen'.
```

I am guessing that you can't have conditional tab rendering?

```
     <ShowTab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarActiveTintColor: 'white',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#4b7894',
          tabBarLabelStyle: {
            fontWeight: '600',
          },
          tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            height: 4,
          },
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#021f2e',
          },
        }}>
        <ShowTab.Screen name="About">
          {() => <ShowInfo show={show} />}
        </ShowTab.Screen>
        <ShowTab.Screen name="Schedule">
          {() => <ShowSchedule show={show} />}
        </ShowTab.Screen>

        {show.feedurl && (
          <ShowTab.Screen name="Podcasts">
            {() => <ShowPodcasts show={show} />}
          </ShowTab.Screen>
        )}
        
      </ShowTab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why it wasn't working, but I changed it to

```
{ show.feedurl != '' && (
```

and now it's working, I'd love to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure, glad you fixed it tho

Comment: Because `show.feedurl && something` will render `show.feedurl` if `show.feedurl` is falsy (empty string, 0, null, undefined). here it's empty string, so here it renders an empty string which is not valid

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try replacing your .Screen code with this? I never used react native or react navigation but this is what I found with a little bit of research.

````js
    <ShowTab.Screen name="About" children={() => <ShowInfo show={show} />} />
    <ShowTab.Screen name="Schedule" children={() => <ShowSchedule show={show} />} />

    {show.feedurl && (
        <ShowTab.Screen name="Podcasts" children={() => <ShowPodcasts show={show} />} />
    )}
    ```
````

Comment: It appears to never work now, ```Error: A navigator can only contain 'Screen', 'Group' or 'React.Fragment' as its direct children (found '``'). To render this component in the navigator, pass it in the 'component' prop to 'Screen'``